# Krpano autorotate not working

Tags: javascript, xml, krpano

I'm using the [KRpano](http://krpano.com) panorama viewer and so far it works fine but now I want the image to autorotate but I'm having trouble with it.

here's my code:

```
var viewer = createPanoViewer({ swf: "/Static/Flash/krpano.swf", xml: "/Static/Flash/custom.xml", target: "krpanoview-container", id: "krpanoSWFObject", width: 600, height: 400 });
viewer.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
viewer.embed();
```

I then created the `custom.xml`-file inside the same folder as the `krpano.swf`. The XML looks like this:

```
<krpano>
  <autorotate enabled="true" />
  ...
</krpano>
```

But it doesnt seem to work. Can someone maybe tell me what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Because the autorotate tag is simple and well written, I can suspect two or more issues:

- First, be sure your XML file is consistent: check you don't have a syntax issue in your XML file. To achieve this, just drag-n-drop it in your browser; rcent browsers analyse XML files and inform when there is a syntax issue.
- Is the custom.xml file actually read by KRPano? The point is that according to its content, it can fail to be read or just to be inaccessible to KRPano. To be sure it is read, place an event "onxmlcomplete" that place traces in the console, like :

```
<krpano logkey="true>
    ...
    <events name="debugEvents" onxmlcomplete="showlog(true);trace('My XML file is well read');" />
    ...
</krpano>
```

Then when your pano loads, you should see the console popping with the text typed in. If nothing happens, the issue is that KRPano cannot access to your XML file as you defined it in your JS.

- When you are sure the XML is well imported and read, the issue can comes from an action that switch off the autorotate. Check twice all your XML files (all and every "include") does not call something like:

```
    switch(autorotate.enabled);
    toggle(autorotate.enabled);
    set(autorotate.enabled, false);
    ...
```

- When all this above failed, check your KRPano revision (like 1.17) and set all krpano tag with version="1.17" like:

```
    <krpano version="1.17">...
```

If everything above failed to help you, check you are using the more recent KRPano (1.18 or 1.19pre) and you are correctly inserting the pano in your page.

Regards